# Using createBottomTabNavigator with createStackNavigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native, I am trying to create a tab bar and also use createStackNavigator to allow me to link screens together. I have been able to get this to work with the following code.

```js
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: HomeScreen
    
},
  Events: { 
    screen: EventScreen

  },
  About: { 
    screen: AboutScreen
  }
},
 { tabBarOptions: { 
    showIcon: true,
    activeTintColor: '#D4AF37',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      style: {
       backgroundColor: 'white', 
},
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
  }
}
 }
);

const MyStack = createStackNavigator({ 
Tabs: {
   screen: TabNavigator
 }, 
 Home: {
     screen: HomeScreen
   },
 Sermons: {
     screen: SecondActivity
  },
   Map: {
     screen: MapScreen
   }
 },
   {
   initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
 }
);
  
export default createAppContainer(MyStack);
```

The only problem is that when I run my app each page says tabs in the header as shown below. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: App]

Comment: rather than that, create your own custom header and just import it in each component

Comment: I need to go from one page to another from the header with a back button

Comment: Becky - did you try my solution? it should work and you can style every header the way you like.

Comment: I still have the same problem of every screen having the seem header name, even when I set them as different

Comment: set `headerMode:'none',` on your `StackNavigator`

Comment: that didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `navigationOptions`:

```js
 Home: {
   screen: HomeScreen,
   navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
     title: `My home page`
   })
 }
```

Comment: doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I'm sure this is working. You can also try in the Screen: `static navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
      title: 'Home screen!'
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass navigationOptions to your different stacks!

```
    const ENTRYSTACK= createStackNavigator(
  {
    ENTRY: {
      screen: ENTRYSCREEN,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: "Your Header Title",
        headerTitleStyle:{
          color: "white",
          alignSelf: "center"         // some styling if u want 
        },
        headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor: "#a51717"
        }
      }
    }, some other screens/stacks ... 
  }
)
```

Comment: I still have the same problem of every screen having the seem header name, even when I set them as different

Comment: did you remove initialroutename?

Comment: doesn't fix the problem